# error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'type' in Angular. while running ng build

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, node-modules, angularfire2

**Error: node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/dist/auth-compat/index.d.ts:53:10 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'type'.**

Try to **build angular code**, i am getting below **error in cmd**.

```
 import { type User, type Unsubscribe, type ActionCodeInfo, type UserCredential, type Auth, type IdTokenResult, type MultiFactorError, type MultiFactorResolver, type PopupRedirectResolver, type Dependencies, type AuthCredential, type ApplicationVerifier, type ConfirmationResult, type AuthProvider, type MultiFactorUser, type NextOrObserver, type ErrorFn, type CompleteFn, type ActionCodeSettings, type Persistence, type PhoneAuthCredential } from "@firebase/auth";
            ~~~~


Error: node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/dist/auth-compat/index.d.ts:53:10 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'type'.
```

Some times i get error in **all firebase compat** file like **database-compat, storage-compat, etc**.

This is my **package.json** file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1081.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^9.4.1",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "http-client": "^4.3.1",
    "http-server": "^13.0.2",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "karma-viewport": "^1.0.8",
    "mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.1.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "uuid-generator-ts": "^1.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.46",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
```

This is my **tsconfig.json** file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
}
```

I try to reduce **firebase and @angular/fire version in 9.0.0 and ^7.0.0** based on **Angular version**. But this is not working.

I **ref this link** to change version. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Help to solve this problem.

I try to solve that problem in many ways, but i can't solve this.

I expecting to solve the problem as soon as possible.

When install all dependencies in **my angular application using npm install**, after that automatically **type** can add infornt of all **firebase modules** like **Unsubscribe, User, ActionCodeInfo, etc**. Below i add the **firebase node modules index.d.ts** code.

`import { type User, type Unsubscribe, type ActionCodeInfo, type UserCredential, type Auth, type IdTokenResult, type MultiFactorError, type MultiFactorResolver, type PopupRedirectResolver, type Dependencies, type AuthCredential, type ApplicationVerifier, type ConfirmationResult, type AuthProvider, type MultiFactorUser, type NextOrObserver, type ErrorFn, type CompleteFn, type ActionCodeSettings, type Persistence, type PhoneAuthCredential } from "@firebase/auth";`

After install all dependencies, try to build the application. i get the above mentioned error (**node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/dist/auth-compat/index.d.ts:53:10 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'type'.**).

My question is how to solve the error in my application?.

One month ago above mentioned **firebase and @angular/fire version is working**. But **last one month** it through the **error**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Update my question please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update **Angular version 12 to 13**. Using below command.

`ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 --force`

Then update **typescript 4.3.5 to 4.6.2**. Using below command.

`npm i typescript@4.6.2`

After these two update, the above mentioned problem is solved.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. No one tells you that you need to update typescript version as well. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for this info.  I'm running into it.  I was on Angular 13 so i updated typescript to 4.6.2 and my Angular doesn't like it.  So I am going to try to refresh angular as well.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the word `type` in your import statements. Try this instead:

```
import {
    User,
    Unsubscribe,
    ActionCodeInfo,
    UserCredential,
    Auth,
    IdTokenResult,
    MultiFactorError,
    MultiFactorResolver,
    PopupRedirectResolver,
    Dependencies,
    AuthCredential,
    ApplicationVerifier,
    ConfirmationResult,
    AuthProvider,
    MultiFactorUser,
    NextOrObserver,
    ErrorFn,
    CompleteFn,
    ActionCodeSettings,
    Persistence,
    PhoneAuthCredential
} from "@firebase/auth";
```

Comment: I am using **import**  like this. `import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';`

Comment: The problem coming from that path. `node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/dist/auth-compat/index.d.ts`.

Comment: update my question please check it again.